# Get SVG Data from Highcharts without displaying the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having an issue with trying to get the raw SVG data from Highcharts, but in this case I can't display the charts I have before getting the data I need.

How can the SVG Data be retrieved through the Highcharts `GetSVG` method without displaying the chart.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with this, I was able to get it to work by creating an element and not attaching it to the DOM.

```
var x = $(document.createElement('div')).highcharts({
// add options here
}
```

Below is the fiddle that solves the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/1p81fbzs/262/